# Transform laltitude and longitude in python pandas using pyproj

Tags: python, pandas, latitude-longitude, pyproj, epsg

I have a dataframe as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
     'epsg': [4326, 4326, 4326, 4203, 7844],
     'latitude': [-34.58, -22.78, -33.45, -33.60, -30.48],
     'longitude': [122.31, 120.2, 118.55, 140.77, 115.88]})
```

Here is the function to transform the lat/long if it is not based on 4326:

```
def transfform_lat_long(inproj:int, outproj:int, x1, y1):
    proj = pyproj.Transformer.from_crs(inproj, outproj, always_xy=True)
    x2, y2 = proj.transform(x1, y1)
    return outproj, x2, y2
```

I try to apply the function over the data frame so that its lat/long/epsg will be updated if the epsg is not 4326

```
df[['epsg','latitude', 'longitude']] = df.apply(lambda row:
    transfform_lat_long(row.epsg, 4326, row.latitude, row.longitude) if row.epsg != 4326)
```

It produces syntax error. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May I suggest you an optimization if your dataframe is large. Instead of apply the transformation for each row, apply the transformation for each group of `epsg` then avoid to check if the `outproj` is `inproj` using a boolean mask:

```
def transfform_lat_long(inproj: int, outproj: int, x1: pd.Series, y1: pd.Series):
    proj = pyproj.Transformer.from_crs(inproj, outproj, always_xy=True)
    x2, y2 = proj.transform(x1, y1)
    return pd.DataFrame({'espg': outproj, 'latitude': x2, 'longitude': y2}, index=x1.index)

inproj = 4326
m = df['epsg'] != inproj

df[m] = (df[m].groupby('epsg', group_keys=False)
              .apply(lambda x: transfform_lat_long(x.name, 4326, x['latitude'], x['longitude'])))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   epsg  latitude  longitude
0  4326 -34.58000  122.31000
1  4326 -22.78000  120.20000
2  4326 -33.45000  118.55000
3  4326       inf        inf
4  4326 -30.48000  115.88000
```

Comment: what is x.name for?

Comment: `x.name` is the name of the group. Here the value of the `epsg` column so it's the first argument of your function (`inproj`)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
new_df = df.apply(
    lambda row: transfform_lat_long(row['epsg'], 4326, row['latitude'], row['longitude'])
        if row['epsg'] != 4326
        else row,
    axis=1,
)
```

Output:

```
     epsg  latitude  longitude
0  4326.0    -34.58     122.31
1  4326.0    -22.78     120.20
2  4326.0    -33.45     118.55
3  4326.0       inf        inf
4  4326.0    -30.48     115.88
```